# ios uitextfield to get text and manage label and image how to manage this

Tags: ios, label, bubble-sort

i want to make speech bubble like app , if you have any demo link please share with me ,here i share a image please HELP ME 
i have one text field , then this textfield text set in label with dynamic height and image also set dynamic height width 
here i share a image link please check 
[link image screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4i59ny0tcso290/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Sep%2010%2C%202014%2C%207.32.01%20PM.png?dl=0) 
i have facing lost of problem here is my code

here is my code

```
-(void)TextHeight
{

    NSString *message = txtmain.text;
    CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontsize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.width, 9999.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];


    CGFloat height =  size.height+60;
    CGFloat width =  size.width+50;

   // NSLog(@"w== %f,, H==%f",width,height);

    if(lblpositionwidth < 210)
    {
        if(lblPositionDynamicChange > 33)
        {
          lblPositionDynamicChange=lblPositionDynamicChange-3;

        }

         lblTextInBubbles.frame=CGRectMake(lblPositionDynamicChange, lblTextInBubbles.frame.origin.y, width, height);

        lblpositionwidth=lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.width;
    }else
    {
        if(lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.height < 125)
        {
            if( lblPositionDynamicChangeY > 38 )
            {
                lblPositionDynamicChangeY=lblPositionDynamicChangeY-10;

            }
            lblTextInBubbles.frame=CGRectMake(lblTextInBubbles.frame.origin.x, lblPositionDynamicChangeY, lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.width, height);
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[lblTextInBubbles.text length]);

        }
    }
    lblTextInBubbles.lineBreakMode=6;
   // NSLog(@"After= %f",lblTextInBubbles.frame.origin.x);
    [self setBubblesImageFrame];
}
-(void)setBubblesImageFrame
{
  imgbabble.frame = CGRectMake(lblTextInBubbles.frame.origin.x -55, lblTextInBubbles.frame.origin.y-55, lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.width+100, lblTextInBubbles.frame.size.height+100);
}

- (IBAction)txt_editing:(id)sender
{
    [self TextHeight];
    lblTextInBubbles.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   /* if([txtmain.text length] > 16)
    {
        NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,,,,, width=%f,,,,height=%fds",imgbabble.frame.origin.x,imgbabble.frame.origin.y,imgbabble.frame.size.width,imgbabble.frame.size.height);

        imgbabble.frame=CGRectMake(imgbabble.frame.origin.x-10, imgbabble.frame.origin.y-5, 160, 64);
      //  NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,,,,, width=%f,,,,height=%fds",imgbabble.frame.origin.x,imgbabble.frame.origin.y,imgbabble.frame.size.width,imgbabble.frame.size.height);
    }*/
    lblTextInBubbles.text=txtmain.text;
    lblTextInBubbles.textColor= [UIColor whiteColor];

    lblTextInBubbles.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        lblTextInBubbles.layer.borderWidth=1.0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use stretchable images and define proper edge insets for each one. You can the easily wrap the around you text rect:

```
UIImage *bubbleImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageBubble~iphone"].CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(13, 13, 13, 21) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

UIImageView *bubbleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bubbleImage];
bubbleImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
bubbleImageView.frame = ...;
```

[image]